# How to open iframe in lightbox

Tags: iframe, lightbox2

I am using

a href='' rel="lightframe">

Lightbox pops out but the content of the lightbox is

"Bad Request -Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand."

I wish to open the iframe in lightbox.
Need HELP !!!

Answer (score 1):

Your tag is broken and you did not close the quotes of href attribute.

This works fine for me:

```
<a href="/link/to/page/" data-lightbox="iframe">LinkText</a>
```

Check the [lightbox homepage](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#getting-started) for more samples.